# Problem with &lsquo; and &rsquo; in PostreSQL and Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter, ckeditor

I'm working in a project that uses Codeigniter 3 and PostreSQL, is like a ticket system that works with CKEDITOR, the users paste the answer from Microsoft Word but there is a problem with ‘’ it's being inserted in the database as `&amp;rsquo;` and `&amp;lsquo;` and i'ts not displayed on the site, is there a way to render this, or replace the ‘’ to '' in the whole document?

Thanks

**EDIT**

```
<textarea name="respuesta" id="consulta-body">
<?

if($consulta ->previo){
$chars = htmlspecialchars($consulta->previo, ENT_QUOTES);
echo $chars;
    ?>
</textarea>
```

This is what i have tried no luck at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using entities plugin in ckeditor

Answer (score 0):

Try the below steps to resolve your problem,

1. Before saving the editor content to database:

   **$content = htmlspecialchars($editorcontent, ENT_QUOTES);**
2. Before retrieving the content from database:

   **html_entity_decode($contentfromdb, ENT_QUOTES);**

**Updated:**

To display the data fetched from database you need to follow step 2 of above steps. Edit your code as below

```
<textarea name="respuesta" id="consulta-body">
<?

if($consulta ->previo){
  $chars = html_entity_decode($consulta->previo, ENT_QUOTES);
  echo $chars;
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a tip from CKEditor point of view.

Perhaps you are using [config.htmlEncodeOutput = true](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-htmlEncodeOutput)
which will give the result you are talking about - `&amp;rsquo;`. If you wish to change it at the editor level to `&rsquo;` then please set this configuration setting to `false`.